# How to extract file extension from url

Tags: c++, visual-c++, boost

I have url `http://faq.sipbroker.com/tiki-index.php?page=phone+numbers` and I need to extract the file extension (`php` in thus case) from url.
I can use only C++ and Boost.
How I can do this? there are examples but with some other libls like Poco, etc... but I can use only Boost

Answer (score 2):

The scheme is `http` in this case. Extracting the scheme is very easy since an uri begins with the scheme followed by a colon.
What you are looking for is a part of the `hierarchical part`. To scan this part for a substring you interpret as file extension is a complex task. If you don't want to use a library you might want to have a look into one (like [cppnetlib uri](https://github.com/cpp-netlib/uri)) and copy some code of an existing uri parser. It's really not trivial.

cpp-netlib uri uses `boost::spirit` as parser. You find the implementation in [uri_parser.cpp](https://github.com/cpp-netlib/uri/blob/master/src/detail/uri_parse.cpp)

**EDIT :**
I think you want to extract something you want to interpret as file extension. If you define "file extension" as the characters following the last dot before the (optional) [query part](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986#section-3.4) you could go with a simplified approach.

> The query component is indicated by the first question
> mark ("?") character and terminated by a number sign ("#") character
> or by the end of the URI.

```
std::string::size_type FindNth(const std::string& str, char c, unsigned n){
    std::string::size_type pos = 0;
    for (unsigned i = 0; i < n; ++i)
        pos = str.find(c, pos + 1);
    return pos;
}

std::string FindExension(const std::string& uri) {
    auto path = FindNth(uri, '/', 3);
    if (path == std::string::npos)
        return "";
    auto query = uri.find('?', path);
    auto dot = uri.rfind('.', query);
    if (dot == std::string::npos || dot < path)
        return "";
    return uri.substr(dot, query - dot);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: what is called `scheme` here is, according to the answer of hansmaad, in reality called `hierarchical part`. Anyways, the principles of my answer should be clear.

I would do it the other way round: define all possible schemes, then write a little function that uses `std::string::find` to search for one of the schemes:

```
#include<string>
#include<array>
#include<iostream>

std::string find_scheme(const std::string& url)
{
    static std::array<std::string,2> scheme = {{"php", "whatever"}};

    for(int i=0;i<scheme.size();++i)
    {
        if(url.find(scheme[i])!=std::string::npos)
        {
             return scheme[i];
        }
    }

    return "scheme not found";
}


int main()
{
    std::string your_url = "http://faq.sipbroker.com/tiki-index.php?page=phone+numbers";
    std::cout<<find_scheme(your_url)<<std::endl;
}
```

This is imo safer than extracting some subtring from your url-string, and doesn't even require boost.

**EDIT**: Ok, "safer" is relative ... I meant safer than a hand-written routine. Such an ansatz, however, fails for `http://www.php.com/tiki-index.asp`, for example. In such cases, either adjust my< routine to search after the third slash (--or whatever), or use the library suggested in the other answer.

Comment: Fails on www.baphphone.com/cgi-bin/foo.pl

Comment: Man, add a semicolon and some includes here and there ... my head is not a compiler.

Comment: To the upvoter who *surely* all have reproduced starks result: compiles seamlessly with gcc-4.7.2 by adding an include ... now carry on the swarm behavior.